# display data from table to edit using input tag html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Currently i am still trying to get used with html and php codes. I have created a page that display all contents from database into table that can be edited for each row. When the edit button is clicked it will go to the next page to edit the data. 
Basically to edit, the content should be displayed on the edit page. Some content might be long so i wanted to use the `<textarea>` to fetch them because if i use the `<input>` tag the height cannot be adjusted means the content is displayed only in one line. But then when i used the `<textarea>` tag, it wont display anything at all. It didnt fetch the data. So i wonder if i missed something? I need to fetch/display the content from table with multiple lines. Here is part of code in my edit page.

```html
 <form method="post">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <td>No Seq</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Department</td>
             <td> <select  name="department" style="width: 452px;" value="<?php echo $department; ?>">
                  <option value="IT">it</option>
                  <option value="purchasing">purchasing</option>
                  <option value="finance">finance</option>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Person in Charge</td>
             <td> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Project Title</td>
             <td> <input type="text" name="project_title" size="60" value="<?php echo $project_title;?>"> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Objective</td>
             <td> <textarea type="text" name="objective" style="height: 50px; width: 445px;" value="<?php echo $objective;?>"> </textarea> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>How To Do</td>
             <td> <textarea type="text" name="how_to_do" size="60" style="height: 110px; width: 445px;" value="<?php echo $how_to_do;?>"> </textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Activities</td>
             <td> <textarea type="text" name="activities" size="60" style="height: 110px; width: 445px;" value="<?php echo $activities;?>"> </textarea></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Project Started</td>
             <td> <input type="date" name="prostart" size="60" style="width: 445px;" value="<?php echo $project_started;?>"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Project Completed</td>
             <td> <input type="date" name="procomplete" size="60" style="width: 445px;" value="<?php echo $project_completed;?>"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Target Cost Saving</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="targetcost" size="60" value="<?php echo $target_cost_saving;?>"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Cost Saving After Justification</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="costafter" size="60" value="<?php echo $costsaving_afterjustification;?>"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Cost Saving Monthly After Justification</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="costmonthly" size="60" value="<?php echo $costsaving_monthly?>"></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     <br> <br>
     <input style="width: 80px; height: 30px; margin-left: 750px;" type="submit" name="update" value="Cancel" acti>
     <input style="width: 80px; height: 30px;" type="submit" name="update">
 </form> <br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXTAREA do not accept the parameter **value=**, to set a default content for TEXTAREA, you need to insert the data between the tags, as example below:

```
<textarea type="text" name="objective" style="height: 50px; width: 445px;"><?php echo $objective;?></textarea>
```

See also: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp